# Use jQuery selector as method

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I have page with many inputs inside a set of different divs.

A **subset** of those inputs are created dinamically and they can be also deleted.

By **creating** and **deleting** elements i could have a list of inputs named as shown:

```
<div id="first">
    <input type="text" name="elem[0][elem_option][0][price]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elem[0][elem_option][1][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[0][elem_option][5][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[0][elem_option][21][price]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="elem[3][elem_option][0][price]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elem[3][elem_option][1][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[3][elem_option][3][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[3][elem_option][8][price]" value=""> 
</div><!-- first -->
<div id="second">
    <input type="text" name="elem[1][elem_option][1][price]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elem[1][elem_option][2][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[1][elem_option][7][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[1][elem_option][8][price]" value="">

    <input type="text" name="elem[5][elem_option][5][price]" value="">
    <input type="text" name="elem[5][elem_option][6][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[5][elem_option][8][price]" value=""> 
    <input type="text" name="elem[5][elem_option][9][price]" value=""> 
</div><!-- second-->
    ....
```

I need to select all elements with a name that ends  with [price] and save in a different variable of each div.

I tried a jQuery selector used as method of getelementbyid:

```
first_price_inputs = document.getElementById('first').jQuery('input[name$="[price]"]')
second_price_inputs = document.getElementById('second').jQuery('input[name$="[price]"]')
```

But i get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'jQuery'
```

please help!

Comment: *"I tried a jQuery selector used as method of getelementbyid"*: What makes you think this is even possible? DOM elements don't have a `jQuery` method. I recommend to read some jQuery tutorials: http://learn.jquery.com/.

Comment: is there a way to exclude jquery and get those input elements with basic javascript?

Comment: Sure, jQuey is just a library. You can use `getElementsByTagName` to get all `input` tags and then iterate over them and see which of them has `price` in its name.

Comment: and how it could be done? i searched a lot, but i found only soulutions with `element.name.indexof('prefix')`, that doesn't work in my case

Comment: `if (element.name.indexOf('price') > -1)`... the method name is `indexOf` and it returns `-1` if the substring is not in the string.

Comment: thank you very much.... i was so close!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
first_price_inputs = jQuery('#first input[name$="[price]"]');
second_price_inputs = jQuery('#second input[name$="[price]"]');
```

Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/qRDkq/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
first_price_inputs = jQuery('#first > input[name$="[price]"]')
```

@Cherniv: its not an input of ID `#first`, but a child of the element with ID `#first`of type `input`. So the descendant selector should be used afaik?

Comment: The space *is* the descendant selector. `a b` means *"select all b's that are descendants of a's"*. `>` is the child selector. Selecting an `input` element with ID `first` would be `input#first`.